# Cox-model with exploratory variable measured after start study

Tags: regression, survival, cox-model, kaplan-meier

I'm working with an unusual dataset, where some of the covariates/characteristics are measured after the start of the study (though without a timestamp!).

Basically, it's a dataset about an auction. We're tracking how long it takes for a product to change hands (like when it gets sold). When a product is put up for sale, people can bid on it, and eventually, it might get sold.

Now, would it be okay to include a variable like 'Number of bids' in my analysis? I've heard that in survival analysis, we usually assume that all the information is known right at the beginning of the study (otherwise people use time-varying Cox model). Adding variables that we didn't know about at the start might not fit this assumption I suppose.

What would the implications be of using the'Number of bids' variable? And would it be inherently wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. This kind of prospective variable would introduce temporal collider bias, essentially conditioning on the event before its observed. For variables adjusted in a Cox model, the analyst must critically consider the moving window of available. For instance, number of bids could be considered a time varying covariate for any given time $t$.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Could you refer me to some literature on this?